# How to join Public IP node into existing innodb cluster for MYSQL 8.0.31

Tags: mysql

i want to migrate Azure cloud 3 VM nodes innodb cluster into RED hat cloud.

Existing innodb 3 node cluster using private IP. and i want to join another 2 nodes into existing cluster using PUBLIC IP. but when i am trying to add the instance getting below error.

**There is no local IP address matching the one configured for the local node (x.x.x.x:3306)**

how to add public IP node into existing innodb cluster.

Mysql version: 8.0.31
OS : CentOS 7
Communication Stack: MYSQL

Please help me. i am stuck here.

Comment: 2022-12-05T12:36:04.600336+05:30 0 [ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Error connecting to all peers. Member join failed. Local port: 3306'
2022-12-05T12:36:04.648528+05:30 0 [ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] The member was unable to join the group. Local port: 3306'

Answer (score -2):

It is necessary to check the security group accessed by the ip, and add the corresponding IP and port, but it is not recommended, because the public IP will have a delay in data synchronization

Comment: We checked security group and allowed 3306 ingress and out-gress vise versa. 
i tested telnet using port 3306 and it's working fine vise versa.

Even though MYSQL not accepting to allow public IP  to join cluster.

/etc/hosts also i mentioned public IP and hostname . but no luck.

Comment: using MYSQL communication socket issue is resolved.